# $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}\rfloor =200$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the $x$ :

$$\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}\rfloor =200$$

---

$$x>0 , \to \lfloor \sqrt[3]{8x}\rfloor +\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}\rfloor =200 \\ \lfloor \sqrt[3]{8x}\rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}+\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}\rfloor \in \mathbb{Z}=200$$

now what ?

Comment: Absolute value of $8x$ in the first summand and floor of $8x$ in the second summand. Is that deliberate?

Comment: One solution is $x = 2^3 \cdot 5^6$.

Comment: Assuming $x \in \mathbb{R}$:  $2^3 \cdot 5^6 = 125000 \leq x \leq 128786$

Comment: 3787 solution if $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ they start $x=2^3 5^6$ to $x=2^3 5^6+3787$

Comment: What does this symbol mean anyway?  

⌊. (A newbie excuse)

Comment: @Macindows: it denotes [the Floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)

Comment: I found $125\,000\leq x \leq 128\,787$

Comment: @Raffaele: actually, the upper limit is $<128\,787. 625 =(50.5)^3$

Comment: @GCab Silly me! I restricted to integers without a reason

Answer (score 1):

We can write
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 < x\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8x} } \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {\left\lfloor {8x} \right\rfloor } } \right\rfloor  = 200 \hfill \cr 
  x =  - y < 0\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {\left\lfloor { - 8y} \right\rfloor } } \right\rfloor  = 200 \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Now we have a fundamental property of the floor of a function which says
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  f(x){\rm  continuous}{\rm , monotone (strictly) increasing} \hfill \cr 
  f(x) = {\rm integer}\quad  \Rightarrow \quad x = {\rm integer} \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  \left\lfloor {f\left( {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } \right)} \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {f\left( x \right)} \right\rfloor  \hfill \cr 
  \left\lceil {f\left( {\left\lceil x \right\rceil } \right)} \right\rceil  = \left\lfloor {f\left( x \right)} \right\rfloor  \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
which can be easily proved considering that
$$
f\left( x \right) = \left\lfloor {f(x)} \right\rfloor  + \left\{ {f(x)} \right\} = f\left( {\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  + \left\{ x \right\}} \right)
$$

That it is in particular the case with root function. So, for the case $0<x$
$$
\eqalign{
  & 200 = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8x} } \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {\left\lfloor {8x} \right\rfloor } } \right\rfloor  = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8x} } \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8x} } \right\rfloor   \cr 
  & 100 = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8x} } \right\rfloor   \cr 
  & 100 \le 2\root 3 \of x  < 101  \cr 
  & 50^{\,3}  \le x < \left( {50.5} \right)^{\,3}  \cr} 
$$

While the case $x<0$ does not provide any solution, since
$$
\eqalign{
  & 200 = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {\left\lfloor { - 8y} \right\rfloor } } \right\rfloor  =   \cr 
  &  = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rfloor  + \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of { - \left\lceil {8y} \right\rceil } } \right\rfloor  =   \cr 
  &  = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rfloor  - \left\lceil {\root 3 \of {\left\lceil {8y} \right\rceil } } \right\rceil  =   \cr 
  &  = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rfloor  - \left\lceil {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rceil  \cr} 
$$
which would require
$$
 - 1 \le 200 = \left\lfloor {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rfloor  - \left\lceil {\root 3 \of {8y} } \right\rceil  \le 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the smallest positive integer that solves the equality.  In this case $|8 x| = 8x$ and $\lfloor 8 x \rfloor = 8 x$.

So $2 \sqrt[3]{8 x} = 200$ and thus $x = 125000$.  Clearly we cannot make $x$ smaller than this to solve the equality.

Next, add a "perturbation" to increase $x$ such that the lhs = 201.  This gives the increment 3787 to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It is verified that $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}\rfloor \ge\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor$ therefore $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}\ge 100$ and
$\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor\le100$.We deal only for $x\gt0$ since $x\lt0$ does not work clearly.

►Look first at $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}= 100=\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor$

$$►\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}\rfloor= 100\Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}=100+\epsilon\Rightarrow\lfloor 8x \rfloor=(100+\epsilon)^3;\space0\le\epsilon\lt1\\ 
100^3\le8x\lt100^3+3\cdot100^2+3\cdot100+1=1030301\iff125000\le x\lt128787.625$$
$$►\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor=100\Rightarrow\sqrt[3]{|8x|}=100+\epsilon\Rightarrow |8x|=(100+\epsilon)^3;\space0\le\epsilon\lt1\\100^3\le8x\lt100^3+3\cdot100^2+3\cdot100+1=1030301\iff125000\le x\lt128787.625 $$
Consequently the semi-open interval $[125000,128787.625)$ gives the solution $100+100=200$ $$$$
►►The "next" case is  $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}= 101$ and $\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor=99$. Similar deduction gives

$$►►\lfloor \sqrt[3]{\lfloor 8x \rfloor}= 101\Rightarrow 128787.625\le x\lt132651\\►►\lfloor \sqrt[3]{|8x|}\rfloor=99\Rightarrow121287.375\le z\lt124999.875 $$ An obvious incompatibility for $101+99$ and a fortiori with $(101+n)+(99-n)$.

Thus the solution is $$\color{red}{x\in [125000,128787.625)}$$